# STR_TO_DATE in mariaDB results in NULL

Tags: sql, date, types, mariadb, str-to-date

I have a table with more than 150k entries. The date column contains dates in german format (day.month.year). I can't set 'DATE' as datatype - maria don't accept this format. So I tried to reconfigure the date-string:

```
select datum,
CAST(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d.%M.%Y') AS DATE) 
FROM esf
WHERE ESF_ID = 44421;
```

Due to the 150k I just tried in one line, avoiding performance issues. Result: Maria finds the related entry - performing the cast results in (NULL). I dont know why?

tried different SQL-calls. Nothing worked

Comment: You need to find the row with the invalid date (example: `select str_to_date("16.12 2023","%d.%m.%Y");` There is a `.` missing!)

Comment: BTW: you need a `m` in stead of an `M` in your date format. (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format )

Comment: That's the clue! m>M made my day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: note if you are doing queries on the date, you should be storing a `date`, rather than a string representation of it. *Structured* Query Language implies structured (hence typed correctly) data.

Comment: @danblack thank for the hint. exaxtly this was the purpose of the above trial. maria can't work with german date format (or I am too stupid to make "her" do so :D). so I wanted to reformat the string (e.g. 10.01.2022) so Maria can update the datatype to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `%M` in STR_TO_DATE expects a full month name in current locale, instead use `m` for a 2 digit month:
2. STR_TO_DATE returns a date, so there is no need to cast a date to date.

See also: [STR_TO_DATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the date:

```
SELECt *
FROM (
   SELECT
      LEFT(datum,2) as D,
      MID(datum,4,2) as M,
      RIGHT(RTRIM(datum),4) as Y
   FROM esf
  ) x
WHERE d<1 or d>31 or m<1 or m>12 or y<1970 or y>2023;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/lfkKrFBn) needs some improvement for month with less than 31 days!  (and of course the range in the year should be adapted to your own needs)

Comment: maria didnt find matching rows. So I think every date is "valid". Beside of that: it should definitely work for one specific row as I tried in the given example, shouldnt it?

Comment: Only when the `datum` is a correct date, but obviously the `%M`  was the problem 